# "Runtime Error '429': ActiveX component can't create object" error with CreateObject("OracleInProcServer.XoraSession")

Tags: excel, vba, oracle, active-directory, oracle12c

When I try to run a '.xla' excel file, it gives me a

> runtime error '429' 'ActiveX component can't create object"

at the line `CreateObject("OracleInProcServer.XoraSession")`

I'm using Microsoft Excel 2016 and Oracle Client 12c on Windows 10. It used to work just fine before when the Oracle Client 11g but it suddenly has stopped working I can't seem to figure out why. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: https://community.oracle.com/thread/2536302

Comment: It is a dll or exe COM server. What bitness are the clients/servers. If it is a dll you can force it into DLLHOST as bitness doesn't matter in COM EXE files.